# atom-beautify & php-cs-fixer

Tags: php, atom-editor, php-cs-fixer, atom-beautify

I am a new programmer and I need your help.
I'm pretty much new to Atom editor, but setup some nice packages like Atom Beautify. After using it in a **html / php** file I'm getting the error "Could not find 'php-cs-fixer' . The program may not be installed. The strange thing is, I did install the package php-cs-fixer but nothing happens.

My system is Windows.

Anyone got an idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 10):

1. You must have installed "php" usually when installing the Wamp or Xampp servers are installed by default.
2. Download the file "php-cs-fixer.phar" https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer
3. In the CMD execute this command: php where.exe
4. You get a path, that path copy in: Open Atom Packages / Atom Beautify / Settings / Executables / PHP

[image]

5. In the same folder where the php.exe is located copy the file "php-cs-fixer.phar"
6. Redo the previous process with the CMD and the Atom in PHP-CS-Fixer "

[image]

Comment: These screenshots and explanation were really helpful. The explanation at https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer is completely ununderstandable to me. It says 'place "php-cs-fixer.phar" *anywhere* on your computer. ??? This is wrong, your explanation explains it should be in the folder where php.exe is. And the Atom-beautify settings are confusing too. One directly sees a heading 'PHP'. If you place the path at PHP-CS-Fixer path there, that's the wrong place.You should ignore that and go inside 'executables>PHP and place the pathes there. Thanks for giving the correct instructions!

Comment: @PaulGobée The note about adding `PHP-CS-FIXER` at `executables>PHP-CS-FIXER` is valid and highly recommended as the other option is now deprecated. However, I am not sure if it HAS to be at the same location of `php.exe` given that the documentation states otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about in Windows, but on Mac and Linux, I do the following. You may be able to do this with Git Bash in Windows.

Install php-cs-fixer with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (via [PHP-CS-Fixer Instructions](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer))

```sh
brew install php-cs-fixer
```

Confirm php-cs-fixer was installed

```sh
which php-cs-fixer
```

Answer (score 3):

Just run this command in terminal, then it will work perfectly:

```
$ composer global require friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer
```

Everything will be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

its because you need to install php cs fixer, the atom extension is trying to use it but its not currently installed on your system, install it here:
https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer

Comment: I entered that link before and I download  php-cs-fixer.phar file, but I didn't know how to follow the instructions,  If you could clarify the procedure to me I will appreciate that, as I said before I am on Windows system, Thanks for your help

Comment: first of all, do you have `PHP` in your shell ? if so, you should install `composer` (https://getcomposer.org/) and with it install php-cs

Comment: I have PHP because I am using XAMP

Comment: well that not's an answer to my question, so i reformulate it. When you open your terminal a type `php --version` do you have a version output ? Without it, it's a bit hard to develop any PHP application

Comment: perfect so you have just to follow these steps install composer -> install php-cs-fixer , that's all!

Comment: So far so good, but is there a specific location should I store the composer and the php-cs-fix

Comment: you have to install composer globaly in your case ( i think in windows its by default the case) for test the installation `composer -V`, if working then type `composer global require friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer` , after that it should be ok

Comment: I already did that, but I need to set the path for PHP-CS-Fixer Config File & PHP-CS-Fixer Path in atom-beautify

Comment: i get these links, let me know if u have some trouble https://atom.io/packages/php-cs-fixer https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/145

Comment: I read that comments but didn't understand anything from there!

Comment: The github issue was to help to find the path of php-cs-fixer as you said earlier ( i'm not on windows so, i cant' really help you on this ) but i think its like `C:\xamp\bin\php\php7.1.7\php-cs-fixer.phar`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install manually the php-cs-fixer using the following steps:

- You can use yum, apt, and other methods of installing a software or a .exe for windows
- Get the path to the installed binary, for example for me i checked using `whereis php-cs-fixer` and I got `/usr/bin/php-cs-fixer`
- Go to `Packages > Atom Beautify > Settings > Executables > PHP-CS-FIXER` then in the `Binary/Script Path` give the path of the php-cs-fixer above (`/usr/bin/php-cs-fixer`)
- Enjoy beautify.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was originally installing with composer. Composer does not put a .phar file into the /bin folder.

Download the .phar file (https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer#locally) and place it somewhere explicitly, then put that location in settings->executables->PHP-CS-Fixer path

Answer (score 0):

The manual way did work for me and this how I went about it;

1. I download `php-cs-fixer` manually.

```
    $ wget https://cs.symfony.com/download/php-cs-fixer-v3.phar -O php-cs-fixer
```

or with `curl`

```
    $ curl -L https://cs.symfony.com/download/php-cs-fixer-v3.phar -o php-cs-fixer
```

2. Then I fixed the rights and moved it to the right directory.

```
    $ sudo chmod a+x php-cs-fixer
    $ sudo mv php-cs-fixer /usr/local/bin/php-cs-fixer
```

3. Finally, I ran `php-cs-fixer` and it worked.

full [link](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/master/doc/installation.rst)

Answer (score 0):

1. make an empty folder somewhere. example: C:\Programs\php-cs-fixer
2. run `composer require friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer`
3. open atom and go to
   settings -> packages -> atom beautify -> settings -> executables ->
   php cs fixer input the path there:
   `C:\Programs\php-cs-fixer\vendor\bin\php-cs-fixer.bat`
4. optionally:
   add `C:\Programs\php-cs-fixer\vendor\bin` to windows env path so you
   can use it from cli